# Parse data with beatifulsoup using Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup

I have thousands of URLs in a text file, now I want to extract title and price from a product link. I tried to implement threads to do it faster but seems that it's not working correctly, producing duplicate data and executing script too long. Without using threads, the script works as expected.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import lxml
import threading

def runner(fname):

  global lck
  lck.acquire()
  with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      r = requests.get(line)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
      try:
        title = soup.find('h1', id='itemTitle').text.trim().encode('utf-8')
        price = soup.find('span', itemprop='price').text.trim().encode('utf-8')
      except:
        price = "No price" 

      with open("Data.csv", 'a', newline='',) as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([title, price]) 
  lck.release()


lck = threading.Lock()
fname = "ProductLinks.txt"
threads = []
for i in range(0, 3):
  t = threading.Thread(target = runner, args = (fname, ))
  threads.append(t)
  t.start()

for t in threads:
  t.join()
```

Can someone please guide me, on how to do it correctly, so it can extract and save data parallelly

Comment: in what variable do you store the data?

Comment: extracted data stored in title price and then being written to a CSV file, basically, i need to execute function runner in parallel

Comment: hmmm, I see what are you using to write to the CSV file? pandas?

Comment: no standard csv module

Comment: I don't quite get why you are using the `lck` variable

Comment: could you possibly try removing `lck = threading.Lock()`, `global lck`, `lck.acquire()` and  `lck.release()` and tell me if this works.

Answer (score 2):

It is producing duplicate results because when you create the threads you call the same function three times.

```
t = threading.Thread(target = runner, args = (fname, ))
```

When you execute the above line, the argument always stays `fname` which as far as I understand it is always `"ProductLinks.txt"`. Therefore your program will go into `runner` and there I see that you loop over all the lines of the text.

I suspect that what you want to "parallelise" is exactly that looping over the text lines? Then you would need to write a function `parse_line` and pass this one into the threading environment.

I would also suggest that you store the values in a dict and export to `csv` in the end because am not sure if the `open` environment is thread-safe.

```
def parse_line(line, result_dict):
    r = requests.get(line)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    try:
        title = soup.find('h1', id='itemTitle').text.trim().encode('utf-8')
        price = soup.find('span', itemprop='price').text.trim().encode('utf-8')
        result_dict[title] = price
    except:
        result_dict['No title'] = "No price"
```

Now, say that you have a list with all the lines in your file as strings. You can achieve that by doing the following

```
file_lines = []
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        file_lines.append(line)
```

Then you can call this function using `Threading` over the list of all lines in your file

```
my_dict = {}
for input_line in file_lines:
    t = threading.Thread(target = parse_line, args = (input_line, my_dict))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Finally you can export your dict to `csv` using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(my_dict).to_csv("Data.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and where do I have to pass file name from which i need to read URLs and how to specify an amount of threads that should be used?

Comment: You will need to open the file first and read all the lines (I will edit my answer to show that). Also, you do not really need to specify the number of threads. Just loop over the lines and create a new thread.

Comment: Thanks for your help, seems data is being written, had problem with pandas but i figured it out, but another problem is that time to complete the scripts takes longer than without using Threads, maybe i have something wrong in my code, here is the full version based on your answer. https://pastebin.com/PbZwWnWj